# Check if mouse is with loading animation in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, mouse

I'm trying to automate tasks on a webpage.

That page has a loading animation that I can't make selenium detect but I noticed that when the page is in that state, my mouse has a loading animation (loading circle).

Is it possible to detect when the mouse is in the loading animation with Selenium?

Comment: Can you share a link to that page? I believe we will be able to catch that loading animation element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you could check the cursor style with

```
element.getCssValue("cursor");
```

Maybe it will be "wait"

Check possible values here

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor

Comment: In my case it was actually "progress". Thank you so much for the useful information! One more thing, what should be the element be?

Comment: I guess body should do. Like this driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"))